# How can I include parentheses inside string using string literals in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

**Problem**

I'm trying to alter a variable to my desired string which includes a set parentheses. When doing so, it's trims off the closing parenthesis. I believe I have to include string literals but unsure on how to do so for my particular scenario.

**Script (Partial)**

```sql
...
IF col_datatype = 'varchar' THEN
    SET col_datatype = 'varchar(30)';
    SELECT col_datatype;
END IF;
SELECT col_datatype;
...
```

**Output**

[image: Output]

Comment: Have you tried using the backquote, i.e ` ?

Comment: SET @col_datatype = 'varchar(30)';
    SELECT @col_datatype;  doesn't do cut of the parasynthesis

Comment: @PrakharLondhe did the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the backquote `. This is used when you wish to insert non-formatted strings into the database.